# Multiple REST calls timing out in Spring Boot web application

Tags: multithreading, spring-boot, resttemplate

I created a Spring Boot (1.4.2) REST application. One of the @RestController methods needs to invoke a 3rd party API REST operation (RestOp1) which returns, say between 100-250 records. For each of those records returned by RestOp1, within the same method, another REST operation of the same 3rd party API (RestOp2) must be invoked. My first attempt involved using a Controller class level ExecutorService based on a Fixed Thread Pool of size 100, and a Callable returning a record corresponding to the response of RestOp2:

```
// Executor thread pool - declared and initialized at class level
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);

// Get records from RestOp1
ResponseEntity<RestOp1ResObj[]> restOp1ResObjList
  = this.restTemplate.exchange(url1, HttpMethod.GET, httpEntity, RestOp1ResObj[].class);
RestOp1ResObj[] records = restOp1ResObjList.getBody();

// Instantiate a list of futures (to call RestOp2 for each record)
List<Future<RestOp2ResObj>> futureList = new ArrayList<>();

// Iterate through the array of records and call RestOp2 in a concurrent manner, using Callables.
for (int count=0; count<records.length; count++) {

  Future<RestOp2ResObj> future = this.executorService.submit(new Callable<RestOp2ResObj>() {

    @Override
    public RestOp2ResObj call() throws Exception {
      return this.restTemplate.exchange(url2, HttpMethod.GET, httpEntity, RestOp2Obj.class);
    }
  };

  futureList.add(future);
});

// Iterate list of futures and fetch response from RestOp2 for each
// record. Build a final response and send back to the client.
for (int count=0; count<futureList.size(); count++) {

  RestOp2ResObj response = futureList.get(count).get();
  // use above response to build a final response for all the records.
}
```

The performance of the above code is abysmal to say the least. The response time for a RestOp1 call (invoked only once) is around 2.5 seconds and that for a RestOp2 call (invoked for each record) is about 1.5 seconds. But the code execution time is between 20-30 seconds, as opposed to an expected range of 5-6 seconds! Am I missing something fundamental here?

Comment: Could you add the initialization of your `executorService`?

Comment: @ilopezluna I added the initializtion of the executor service at the top of the code snippet. That is a member of the class, obviously declared outside the method in question.

Comment: Ok, seems ok to me. Have you check if your task has been executed parallelized? For example logging the thread name, you can define the name when create the pool of threads: http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2014/11/executorservice-10-tips-and-tricks.html

Comment: @ilopezluna that is a great set of tips. Even if task is not executed parallelized, I am wondering what is the holdup. I will try some logging that may hopefully shed some light. Is there any better way/pattern for doing this?

Comment: I don't know any pattern to achieve that, what I suggest you is to log the name of threads (to see if they are running parallelized), the execution time of each task and calculate the average time (just to be sure the response time of the api is what you expected) and then you will have all the info to see who is taking all the time. Maybe is just about one single query which takes more seconds than you expect. Try it and tell us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the service you are calling fast enough to handle that many requests per second?

There is an async version of RestService is available called [AsyncRestService](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/AsyncRestTemplate.html). Why are you not using that?

I would probably go like this:

```
    AsyncRestTemplate asyncRestTemplate = new AsyncRestTemplate(new ConcurrentTaskExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100)));

    asyncRestTemplate.exchange("http://www.example.com/myurl", HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<>("message"), String.class)
            .addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<ResponseEntity<String>>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(ResponseEntity<String> result) {
                    //TODO: Add real response handling

                    System.out.println(result);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
                    //TODO: Add real logging solution

                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
```

Comment: Yes, the 3rd party service can handle much larger number of concurrent requests. The individual response times are 1.5-2.5 seconds on RestOp1 and that of RestOp2 is 1-1.5 seconds. That is why I expected a maximum response time of 5-7 seconds on my call. I looked at AsyncRestService and what I don't know is how to configure it to use something like Apache's AsyncHttpClient and handle success, cancel and error conditions. Is there any good code examples (in a Spring Boot web app context) that I can refer to?

Comment: I extended the answer for you a little bit.

Comment: Thanks for the code. Since I will be calling the `asyncRestTemplate.exchange(...)` 150-250 times potentially, how do I coordinate the completion of all the ListenableFutureCallbacks? Will ListenableFuture<List<RestOp2ResObj>> be the return type of this service method, sending it back to the controller? I am trying to figure that part out, where multiple responses need to coordinated and sent back. My understanding of ListenableFuture and DeferredResult is weak, which is why I am having so much difficulty.

Answer (score 1):

Your question involves two parts :

1. multiple API callbacks asynchronously
2. handle timeouts (fallback)

both parts are related as you've to handle the timeout of each call.

you may consider use Spring Cloud (based on spring boot) and use some out of the box solution based on OSS Netflix stacks.

The first (timeouts) on should be a circuit breaker [hystrix](https://spring.io/guides/gs/circuit-breaker/) based on feign client

The second (multiple requests) this is an architecture issue, using native Executors isn't a good idea as it will not scale and has a huge maintenance costs. You may relay on [Spring Asynchrounous Methods](https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/) you'll have better results and fully spring compliant.

Hope this will help.

Comment: I started looking into AsyncRestTemplate, based on the previous answer. In the link you provided, it seems to cover running the code in a different thread (empowered by @Async), that is not managed by Spring? I am a bit confused with which way to go.

Comment: It's all about stick with simplicity and the Don't Repeat your Self principle. Using @Async will handle for you the bothering to manage thread life cycle. Here's a more explained example. http://www.baeldung.com/spring-async

Comment: I looked at the example link. If I was making a single call, the code makes the benefit of `@Async` apparent. In my case, I still need to worry about how to coordinate the results of the multiple API calls and send them back as a single response. In that scenario, I am wondering how `@Async` is going to do all that for me, if I don't come up with some thread synchronization code.

Comment: defintely , you can loop on a service method annotated with @Async and store the resulted Future into a list, then within a while(true) loop you can probe fro the result within the Future(s) to build your result. The main benefit is that you don't have to deal with Executor at all